# How to redirect a URL to subdomain, when it is in the same directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm trying to redirect a URL to a subdomain, but the directory for the subdomain is in the root of the main, so I keep getting a redirect loop error.

OLD URL - `http://thisisimysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g`
NEW URL - `http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g`

Here is what I've tried (I've added line breaks just for readability):

```
Redirect 301 
/instruments/award/mbac-18-g 
http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g
```

˄I get a redirect loop error.

```
Redirect 301 
http://thisismysite.com//instruments/award/mbac-18-g
http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g
```

˄Nothing happens at all.

*Note:  The legacy.thisismysite.com directory (/legacy) is within the root directory of thisismysite.com. I don't want to redirect *all* old urls from main to legacy, as some are on main now and some need to move to legacy.

**EDIT:**

Here is my full .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ignore legacy folder/subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/legacy/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Remove trailing slash from ALL urls
# ------------------------------
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect 301 
#http://thisismysite.com//instruments/award/mbac-18-g
#http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thisismysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^instruments/award/mbac-18-g?$     http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g [R=302,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and see how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thisismysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^instruments/award/mbac-18-g/?$ http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g [R=302,L]
```

Change `302` to `301` when you've tested and it works.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I appreciate your help! Unfortunately this isn't working either, nothing happens - it stays on the old URL.  I'll update my question with the rest of what I have in my htaccess file, in case there is something interfering...  thanks!

Comment: Clear your cache and try in a different browser.

Comment: I cleared my cache and refreshed, same thing.  I tried a different browser, same thing.  :/

Comment: And you do have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Check your apache error_log too to see if any errors exist?

Comment: hmmm this is odd, this redirect on a different URL works as expected: `Redirect 301 /discovery-series/discovery-series-guitars http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/discovery-series`

Comment: I checked the error log, I'm not totally sure what to be looking for, but it has a few errors for missing js files, and I searched for anything related to the said URL and There is only this: `[error] [client 173.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/directory/thisismysite.com/html/legacy/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css, referer: http://legacy.thisismysite.com/instruments/award/mbac-18-g`

Comment: no that is not a related error. So the redirect just doesn't work with the one URL?

Comment: I've added a lot of redirects since I started this post - it works on all of them except when the URLs are the same (changing the main domain to the sub-domain). E.G.: `thisismysite.com/segment_a/segment_b` to `legacy.thisismysite.com/segment_c/segment_b` works, but `thisismysite.com/segment_1/segment_2` to `legacy.thisismysite.com/segment_1/segment_2` does not work.